# Phaser 3 Making a text box

Tags: javascript, text, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make text for characters in a platformer game I'm working on. Here is the code I have:

Code in the create method:

```
this.dialog = this.add.text(880, 810, ' ', { font: '30px Futura', fill: '#FFFFFF' }).setOrigin(0.5);
```

Code in the update method:

```
    if ((this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches)) && (this.has("spool") && this.has("needleOne") && this.has("needleTwo")) && this.keyT.isDown) {
        console.log("spool: " + this.has("spool") + " needleOne: " + this.has("needleOne") + " needleTwo: " + this.has("needleTwo"));
        this.dialog.setText('Oh, thanks Peef! Now we can fix Stiches!');
    }
    else if ((this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.goodLamb) || this.checkCollision(this.p1, this.stiches)) && (!(this.has("spool")) || !(this.has("needleOne")) || !(this.has("needleTwo"))) && this.keyT.isDown){
        console.log("spool: " + this.has("spool") + " needleOne: " + this.has("needleOne") + " needleTwo: " + this.has("needleTwo"));
        this.dialog.setText('Peef! Stiches ripped herself again! Can you get the sewing supplies?');
    }
    else{
        this.dialog.setText('');
    }
```

Note that this.p1 is the player, this.goodlamb and this.stiches are characters, and the strings spool, needleOne, and needleTwo represent items in the invetory.

The code currently only shows the text when the player is in collision with the npcs and holds down the T button, which I'm using for interactions in general. But holding down the T button to see the text isn't what I want.

What I'm going for would play out like this: the player is in collision with the npc and presses the button once. One line of text is displayed. After reading the line, the player presses the button again, and the currently line disappears while another line of text appears. This repeats till there are no more lines.

I'm not sure how to pull this off. Any suggestions?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode, employing arcade physics.

Comment: Did my answer, solve your problem? or did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Was struggling to understand your answer. I've managed to find an acceptable alternative, so I technically didn't use it. Hope that's ok.

Comment: Sure thing. no problem, just wanted to know if my answer worked, or you needed some help understanding the proposed solution. If you found a better solution, that is good news.

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to create two `Text - GameObject` and alternate between them, when displaying the different lines of text.
Just with a simple modulo - operation, like seen here `currentLine % 2 == 0`, and depending on the result select one or the other `Text - GameObject`. *(this operation will alternate between `0` and `1`)*

**Abit more Context to the following Example:**

1. There is an array with all messages named `messages`
2. A variable `currentLine` which stores the index of the last displayed message (of `messages` array)
3. Both lines are positioned in the same place, but only one of them is set to be visible.
4. On displaying a new message the expression `currentLine % 2 == 0` just asks if `currentLine` is an *even number*. messages with a even index will displayed on `line0`.

**Here a short working demo, showing the main idea:**
*(I added a tween on showing the text, just for some flair. One could add a tween for hidding the text)*

> The color of the text is only to show, that there 2 different `Text-GameObjects` being used.

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        create
    }
}; 

let line0;
let line1;
let tween;
let currentLine = -1;

let messages = [ 
  "this is the first line", 
  "this is the second line", 
  "this is the third line",
  "DONE! Next Click restart"
];

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click for next message')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    line0 = this.add.text(10, 40)
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});
        
    line1 = this.add.text(10, 40)
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setColor('#00ff00')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    this.input.on('pointerdown',  () => {
        
        //Just for the Demo, to loop the messages
        if(currentLine >= messages.length-1){
          currentLine = -1;
        }
        
        currentLine++;
        let nextLine = messages[currentLine];

        // stop running tween, just to be on the safe side
        if(tween){
           tween.stop();
        }

        // Hide both
        line0.setAlpha(0);
        line1.setAlpha(0);

        //switch between two text gameobjects
        if( currentLine % 2 == 0){
            line0.setText(nextLine);

            // Just to make the fade-in animation
            tween = this.tweens.add({
                targets: [ line0 ],
                alpha: 1,
                duration: 500
            });
        } else {
            line1.setText(nextLine);

            // Just to make the fade-in animation
            tween = this.tweens.add({
                targets: [ line1 ],
                alpha: 1,
                duration: 500
            });
        }
    });
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```